# AngularJS popover not showing content: Rendered Too Early

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, popover

In my AngularJS controller, I call my data service method, which makes a `$http` call to fetch the data needed for page display.

```
appDataService.getById()
  .success(function(document) {
      vm.document = document;
  }
  .error(function(e)){});
```

Everything is displaying fine and most of my popovers are displaying their contents correctly when toggled / clicked on. However, I am having an issue with one of them.

```
    <button popover-directive
            popover-placement="auto"
            popover-content="{{ vm.document.content }}"
            popover-label="Click to View Text "
            class="btn btn-info btn-xs">
    </button>
```

I checked the HTML and can confirm that the `popover-content` is given the correct string value. However, when I click on it, the expected triggered-popover behavior did not occur,

i.e. a new `<div class="popover fade right in">` did not appear.

If the `popover-content` is given a direct value such as `popover-content="testing"`, the `popover` works properly and shows the content when clicked.

It is my strong suspicion that this is due to the asynchronous behavior of my data fetch; my data is not being returned in time for my `popover` to be properly initialized.

Clearly, my popover directive is functioning as it should and I don't think the problem lies with it, but for the sake of a complete picture, I supply my popover directive as follows:

```
function popoverDirective ($document) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '<span>{{label}}</span>',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.label = attrs.popoverLabel;
        $(element).popover({
          trigger: 'click',
          html: true,
          content: attrs.popoverContent,
          placement: attrs.popoverPlacement
        });
      }
    };
  }
```

Any solutions? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the directive attributes are interpolated, consider changing it as:

```
<button popover-directive
        popover-placement="auto"
        popover-content="{{vm.document.content}}"  <!-- Change at this line -->
        popover-label="Click to View Text "
        class="btn btn-info btn-xs">
</button>
```

Also, you need to register an observer since `vm.document.content` is resolved via a promise:

```
function popoverDirective ($document) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '<span>{{label}}</span>',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        function initPopover() {
            scope.label = attrs.popoverLabel;

            // Make sure to remove any popover before hand (please confirm the method)
            $(element).popover("destroy");

            $(element).popover({
              trigger: 'click',
              html: true,
              content: attrs.popoverContent,
              placement: attrs.popoverPlacement
            });
        }

        attrs.$observe("popoverContent", initPopover);
      }
    };
  }
```

**Note** Please remove `bootstrap.min.js` if you are using Bootstrap and you can also remove jQuery. Angular UI team has ported the Bootstrap Javascript to support Angular. Check this out http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap

Comment: Re. the addition of the curly brackets `{{  }}`, that was a typo made only in the question, sorry about that! My actual code does include the brackets and I have updated my question to include the brackets. I will check out the rest of your answer and get back to you, ty, @Shashank Agrawal

Comment: I actually knew of `angular-ui` (that is, even before I read your answer). I only found out after I have written my own directives (as above). As I don't really require many of the features provided by `angular-ui` (just a couple), I chose not to port over to `angular-ui`, especially since they are working, more or less, lol. @Shashank Agrawal

Comment: That worked perfect for me, @Shashank Agrawal. Thank you! Did not think of using `$observe`. Great tip, really!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) instead of directly returning from the service? The goal here would be that it doesn't matter that your function may immediately return or not, because when the asynchronous value is available, the promise will update to contain that value.

You could update the service itself to utilize a promise and either resolve the promise with the value if successful or reject it if there is an error. On the receiving side of this function, the value on the scope will update when the promise has been resolved one way or another.

Comment: My service is actually utilizing a promise! >_< @Xaniff